# How to fix css for progress bar

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass, progress-bar

I'm using react in my app and I'm trying to make a "progress bar" that represents the percentage of the balance that is being used as in this image:
[image]

It's working fine but when the percentage is low (5% or less), the border radius stops working as it should, making the bar appear out of the frame:

[image]

Is there anyway that I can fix this?
Here is the .scss file I'm using for the progress bar

```
.progress-bar {
    background-color: #c5c5cb;
    border-radius: 20px;
    outline: 1px solid #212429;
    outline-offset: -0.5px;
    position: relative;
    height: 20px;
    width: auto;
    margin-right: 12px;
    margin-left: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.progress-done {
    background: linear-gradient(to left, #4A439A, #6950AC);
    border-radius: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 1s ease 0.3s;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `overflow: hidden;` in your `.progress-bar` class.